# Efficiently inserting rows in an Excel spreadsheet using C#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, com, excel-interop

I have a spread sheet that contains ~1500 rows of data. When inserting rows at the top of the spreadsheet, I find that the performance for inserting a single row is approximately 2.5 seconds using the following code:

```
Excel.Range insert_range = _excel.Worksheets["Sheet Name"].Range[insert_address];
insert_range.Insert(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown, Type.Missing);
```

However, if the number of rows is increased to 20 (per insert), the performance remains constant ~2.5 seconds.

Is there any way to increase the speed at which excel inserts these rows?

**EDIT**

The performance appears to correlate to the amount of existing data in the sheet, for example, with a sheet containing 150 rows it takes, 0.23 seconds which seems proportionate.

Thanks

Comment: Adding them to the bottom of the dataset instead of the top will drastically increase performance. Insert forces sheet recalculation for each row I think

Comment: Have you tried setting calculation to manual and turning off screen updating while you perform the inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Folks.

I found that adding the rows to the bottom of the dataset was the best option, as Pynner suggested.

Tim, I had disabled ScreenUpdating and set Calculation = Manual but this didn't have any major impact.

Thanks